# Ambiguous call between decimal and double methods calling using dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, type-conversion

I have some methods to perform data conversion depending of source data type:

```
private static string GetStringValue(String value) { ... }

private static string GetStringValue(DateTime value) { ... }

private static string GetStringValue(Decimal value) { ... }

private static string GetStringValue(Double value) { ... }

private static string GetStringValue(Enum value) { ... }

private static string GetStringValue(Object value) { ... }
```

From source code, I get to call to one of the methods using this:

```
GetStringValue((dynamic)v);
```

This works fine for almost all cases, but I'm getting problems when trying to use it with decimal or double... I got an exception caused by ambiguous call between decimal and double variants.

Is there any way I can workaround this problem?

Comment: it could be any type. The main purpose is to call the correct overload of the method base on the type of v

Comment: do you _really_ need differentiate between double and decimal in to string conversion?

Comment: yes... it may seems a bit awkward, but normally 'v' will come from a property of a Entity Framework POCO class. Depending on the RDMS (SqlServer or Oracle, for example) properties may be generated in any of both ways. That's why I need a solution that works with both.

Comment: I don't get such exception and code executes correctly. There must be something else...

Comment: Finally found the cause. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The exception was raising when 'v' is an Int32. I didn't defined an overload for this type because I thought that it would go down to the 'object' overload, but instead of that, the runtime tries to use the 'decimal' and 'double' ones, which caused the exception.

So the solution is simply to add

```
private static string GetStringValue(Int32 value) { ... }
```